# OpenGl scale + translate not working

Tags: opengl, glut

I have the following problem in Opengl (Glut). I have set the camera posistion to (posx,posy,posz) with gluLookAt, and I need to display an scaled cube in the position (posx+offsetx,posy+offsety,posz+offsetz). I'm doing the following:

```
glPushMatrix(); 
glColor3f(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f);
glTranslatef( posx+offsetx, posy+offsety, posz+offsetz );
glScalef(20,20,60);
glutSolidCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();
```

However the cube does not appear at the right location. I have tried this also by shifting the order of glScalef and glTranslatef (I read this in a similar question). But it did not work either.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that every single function call in that code snippet is deprecated since almost a _decade_, and is not avialable in modern core profiles of OpenGL.

Comment: I realized it is deprecated once I had already programmed a lot. When I searched for on-line examples and simple tutorials they were referring most of them to this function style. Not everyone is an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things - are you switching between modes via `glMatrixMode`?

Are you calling glLoadIdentity() after switching?

I assume you're clearing the depth (if enabled) and color buffers each render?

I don't personally tend to push/pop the matrix unless I'm calling into something third party and I want to maintain my current state... but no harm done.

`gluLookAt` is really just a transformation itself so it may not be doing what you expect.  I assume you have a rendering function that looks like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(posx, posy, posz, // where the eye is located
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // where the eye is looking
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // which direction is "up"

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix(); 
glColor3f(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f);
glTranslatef( posx+offsetx, posy+offsety, posz+offsetz );
glScalef(20,20,60);
glutSolidCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

And that you started up using something like this:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);                                    
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH );
glutInitWindowSize(600,400);                  
glutCreateWindow("Test");                              
glutDisplayFunc(displayFunctionName);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunctionName);
glutMainLoop();
```

This is all using older-style OpenGL direct calls (sometimes called fixed function pipeline) mode which is fine (especially when starting out) but you may want to read up on shaders (GLSL) and how the pipeline works now since this stuff was deprecated in 2004.

Otherwise a more complete code example including your camera positioning code and values plus a screenshot and expected result could be helpful.

Comment: I don't see how this actually answers the question.

Comment: I think there needs to be more information to give a definitive answer; however, if I were guessing, the problem is most likely due one of the transformations being incorrect (either `gluLookAt` or `glTranslate`) so I provided some additional info to help the OP arrive at the correct solution. This may come via revisiting gluLookAt args or the fact that there are (at least) two different matrix modes commonly used.  Even depth/color buffers, culling (and LH/RH rule) could cause abnormalities especially during movement and shader knowledge might provide some insight.

Comment: Well, that's my point. The question as currently stated is un-answerable. One could og course make some guesses, but this doesn't change the bigger picture.

Comment: Well actually it helped. I did not know gluLookAt is a transformation by itself, but just a camera positioning feature. After considering this:  glScalef(20,20,80); glTranslatef( posx/20+offsetx, posy/20+offsety, posz/80+offsetz ); works just fine.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Hope you're enjoying learning this stuff as much as I have.

Comment: @GraemeWicksted Yes I'm indeed. This is my first OpenGl adventure and this code is going to be used for an interesting scientific project. Hopefully I will learn more advanced OpenGl in the future. Thanks!